# Can pointer returned by malloc be changed

Tags: c, malloc, gstring

While programming for a personal project I found out that when I was passing a pointer to one function, its value could not be changed. Example:

```
...
GString *buf = NULL;
buf = g_string_sized_new(64);
somefunc(buf, filename);
...
```

and

```
void somefunc(GString *buf, gchar *filename)
{
    buf = otherfunc(filename); //otherfunc() returns a GString *
}
```

after watching the debugger I observed that when memory allocation for buffer run, then buf=0x80b720 and otherfunc() returned 0x80b750. Although the value of the buffer did not change. So I would like to ask if anyone knows why this happens and if this is a general characteristic of malloc(). In other words, if you pass the pointer returned by a malloc() call to a function, will you be able then to change this value inside or outside the function body?

Answer (score 8):

This has nothing to do with `malloc`.

When you pass a pointer to a function, the function receives a copy of the original pointer. It can modify its own copy of the pointer, but it cannot modify the original pointer.

If you want it to modify the original pointer, you need to pass it the address of the original pointer, which it'll receive as a pointer to a pointer.

```
void somefunc(GString **buf, gchar *filename) { 
    *buf = otherfunc(filename);
}
```

Comment: You may want to mention the term 'pass by value', and that C is [pass by value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) and not [pass by reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference).

Comment: I also want to point out that changing the value of buf inside a function can lead to memory leaks (since now you can't free the originally allocated memory)

Comment: I'd like to add that passing a pointer to a function is pretty much the same as passing an integer to a function, just that the integer happens to be a memory address.